# How to handle the conditional check box selection in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

We have three checkboxes as Left, Right, Both. 
When selecting Left and Right, Both should be disabled.

However, on checking the right and left; checkbox for Both is not disabling. (or) alert('Hello 1') is not firing.

```
document.getElementById('Left').disabled = false;
var isLeft = document.getElementById('Left').checked;

document.getElementById('Right').disabled = false;
var isRight = document.getElementById('Right').checked;


document.getElementById('Both').disabled = false;
var isBoth = document.getElementById('Both').checked;


if (isLeft == true && isRight == true)
{
                alert('Hello 1');
                document.getElementById('Both').checked = false;
                document.getElementById('Both').disabled = true;
}
```

Below is the original code in my JavaScript file

```
if ($("input:radio[name='Swelling']:checked").length > 0) {

        var isChecked = document.getElementById("SwellingYes").checked;

        if (isChecked === true)
        {

                document.getElementById('Left').disabled = false;
                let isLeft = document.getElementById('Left').checked;

                document.getElementById('Right').disabled = false;
                let isRight = document.getElementById('Right').checked;

                document.getElementById('Both').disabled = false;
                let isBoth = document.getElementById('Both').checked;

                if (isLeft && isRight) {
                    alert('Hello 1');
                    document.getElementById('Both').checked = false;
                    document.getElementById('Both').disabled = true;
                }
                if (isBoth) {
                    document.getElementById('Left').checked = false;
                    document.getElementById('Right').checked = false;
                    document.getElementById('Left').disabled = true;
                    document.getElementById('Right').disabled = true;
                }           

        }
}
```

Comment: Please always add ***all*** the code relevant to your question. In this case, you are asking about checkboxes, so include the HTML.

Comment: Based on your question, I believe you also want to check on OR not AND?

Comment: I see no event handlers so not sure how it would be triggered

Comment: This will help: https://jsfiddle.net/8rc4wmz7/2/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to listen on each checkbox's `change` event, then run your code, like so:

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
    Array.prototype.slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('input[type="checkbox"]')).forEach(function (checkbox) {
        checkbox.addEventListener('change', function () {

            document.getElementById('Left').disabled = false;
            var isLeft = document.getElementById('Left').checked;

            document.getElementById('Right').disabled = false;
            var isRight = document.getElementById('Right').checked;


            document.getElementById('Both').disabled = false;
            var isBoth = document.getElementById('Both').checked;


            if (isLeft == true && isRight == true) {
                alert('Hello 1');
                document.getElementById('Both').checked = false;
                document.getElementById('Both').disabled = true;
            }
        });
    });
});
```

```html
    Left:
 <input type="checkbox" id="Left" />
    Right:
    <input type="checkbox" id="Right" />
    Both:
    <input type="checkbox" id="Both" />
```

If you are only supporting modern browsers, you can use a bit of syntactic sugar here as well:

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
    [...document.querySelectorAll('input[type="checkbox"]')].forEach((checkbox) => {
        checkbox.addEventListener('change', () => {
            document.getElementById('Left').disabled = false;
            let isLeft = document.getElementById('Left').checked;

            document.getElementById('Right').disabled = false;
            let isRight = document.getElementById('Right').checked;

            document.getElementById('Both').disabled = false;
            let isBoth = document.getElementById('Both').checked;

            if (isLeft == true && isRight == true) {
                alert('Hello 1');
                document.getElementById('Both').checked = false;
                document.getElementById('Both').disabled = true;
            }
        });
    });
});
```

```html
    Left:
 <input type="checkbox" id="Left" />
    Right:
    <input type="checkbox" id="Right" />
    Both:
    <input type="checkbox" id="Both" />
```

If you wanted to also disable `Left` and `Right`, when `Both` were checked, you could do that, furthermore, it would be wise to not keep querying the dom for your elements, and rather store them inside variables:

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
    let leftBox = document.getElementById('Left');
    let rightBox = document.getElementById('Right');
    let bothBox = document.getElementById('Both');
    [...document.querySelectorAll('input[type="checkbox"]')].forEach((checkbox) => {
        checkbox.addEventListener('change', () => {
            leftBox.disabled = false;
            let isLeft = leftBox.checked;

            rightBox.disabled = false;
            let isRight = rightBox.checked;

            bothBox.disabled = false;
            let isBoth = bothBox.checked;

            if (isLeft && isRight) {
                bothBox.checked = false;
                bothBox.disabled = true;
            }
            if (isBoth) {
                leftBox.checked = false;
                rightBox.checked = false;
                leftBox.disabled = true;
                rightBox.disabled = true;
            }
        });
    });
});
```

```html
Left:
 <input type="checkbox" id="Left" />
    Right:
    <input type="checkbox" id="Right" />
    Both:
    <input type="checkbox" id="Both" />
```

Comment: this is very helpful. This has to be viceversa as well. When we select Both - Label for Left and Right should be disabled

Comment: When we select "Both" ; Left and Right should be disabled.

Comment: @goofyui, added in your request.

Comment: thank you for your help.. I just finding difficult on adding your logic on my existing code. I have added my existing code in the posting, if you could review and advise me would be very helpful

Comment: Thank you so much ryan.. my problem solved.. thanks a lot

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure if this should be a comment or not, but your code only checks to see if it's checked or not once, on page load. If you want it to work properly, you may want to have an event attached or add a loop?

Comment: I agree with you. There has to be an event. My present code logic only checks whether checkbox is checked or not. When Left and Right Checkbox is checked, an event should trigger which disables the Checkbox for the lablel : Both. I am not sure, how to achieve that..

Comment: This should be a comment. I realize that you don't have enough rep. yet to do that, but you will find that answers that should be comments will get downvoted. Focus on posting quality answers until you get the comment privilege.